# Running a userspace process in user mode with Linux kernel call_usermodehelper

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I tried to execute a userspace binary inside the Linux kernel module with `call_usermodehelper`. I found the launched application is running in root mode. Is it possible to run the application in a user mode, for example, named `user1`?

```
int alter_uid_gid(uid_t uid, gid_t gid, struct cred *new)
{
//      struct cred *new;
        new = prepare_creds();
        if (!new)
                return -ENOMEM;
        new->uid = new->euid = new->suid = new->fsuid = KUIDT_INIT(uid);
        new->gid = new->egid = new->sgid = new->fsgid = KGIDT_INIT(gid);
        return commit_creds(new);
}

static int init_func(struct subprocess_info *info, struct cred *new)
{
        printk("[%d]\n", current->pid);
        alter_uid_gid(1000, 1000, new);
        return 0;
}

static int user_process_fork(void *data)
{
    struct subprocess_info *sub_info;
    int ret = 0;
    char *path = (char *)data;
    char *argv[] = {path, NULL};
    static char *envp[] = {"HOME=/", "TERM=linux",
        "PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin", NULL};

    sub_info = call_usermodehelper_setup(argv[0], argv, envp, GFP_ATOMIC,
            init_func, NULL, NULL);
    if (sub_info == NULL) return -ENOMEM;

    ret = call_usermodehelper_exec(sub_info, UMH_KILLABLE);
    pr_info("%s: ret %d\n", __func__, ret);
    do_exit(0);

    return ret;
}
```

---

Based on Milag's comment, I tried to update the u[g/e/s]idin the `init_func()` with `prepare_creds()` and `commit_creds(new)`. In the kernel log, I can see `current->uid` has changed to 1000. But when I run `ps aux`, the process is still in `root` mode. Any idea why?

Comment: does your kernel version pass a (struct cred *) to your `init_func()` ?

Comment: @Milag, I'm not sure whether I get what you said. This is the declaration of the init function `int (*init)(struct subprocess_info *info, struct cred *new),` as a parameter in `call_usermodehelper_setup` function.

Comment: take a look at related kernel sources; it appears that modifying (struct cred *new) members within a supplied init routine like your `init_func()` _might_ be OK, along with possible panic conditions when `CONFIG_SECURITY_SELINUX`  is set and other conditions are met.

Comment: Hello @Milag, in the `init_func()` I updated the `cred`' uid/euid/gid to 1000, but the launched userspace process is still in `root` mode. I'm using `new = prepare_creds(); new->uid = KUIDT_INIT(uid); commit_creds(new);`. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: The idea from last week is modifying member(s) of the `(struct cred *)` passed to your init routine.
Allocating another struct was not suggested; consider this sequence:
kernel allocs+inits a `struct cred`, calls your init routine with a reference to that struct,
then commits _that_ struct _after_ your init routine returns. There's no need for another
prep+commit within an init routine; those creds would be replaced by the kernel's commit.

Comment: Thanks @Milag, assigning `uid` to the `cred` in the params works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After I read some kernel sources and posted comments above, OP later showed updates for a developed kmod.

Short answer: yes, it's possible to set different IDs for a user process launched from a kmod.

After passing an init routine to `call_usermodehelper_setup()`, a related kernel service calls the init routine with a `(struct cred *)`; various uid and gid members can be changed there. For more details, see `call_usermodehelper_exec_async()`

There are related suggestions for kmod versatility:

- add a pair of `#define` for a set of default uid and gid
- add support for module params to set other uid and gid
- optionally provide cmd-line params when the module is loaded

For an example, see [this link](https://devarea.com/linux-kernel-development-kernel-module-parameters/) .

Answer (score 2):

Based on @Milag's comment, the following code makes the new userspace process running in user-mode (using `ps aux` to inspect):

```
int alter_uid_gid(uid_t uid, gid_t gid, struct cred *new)
{
        new->uid = new->euid = new->suid = new->fsuid = KUIDT_INIT(uid);
        new->gid = new->egid = new->sgid = new->fsgid = KGIDT_INIT(gid);
        return 0;
}

static int init_func(struct subprocess_info *info, struct cred *new)
{
        printk("[%d]\n", current->pid);
        alter_uid_gid(1000, 1000, new);
        return 0;
}

static int user_process_fork(void *data)
{
    struct subprocess_info *sub_info;
    int ret = 0;
    char *path = (char *)data;
    char *argv[] = {path, NULL};
    static char *envp[] = {"HOME=/", "TERM=linux",
        "PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin", NULL};

    sub_info = call_usermodehelper_setup(argv[0], argv, envp, GFP_ATOMIC,
            init_func, NULL, NULL);
    if (sub_info == NULL) return -ENOMEM;

    ret = call_usermodehelper_exec(sub_info, UMH_KILLABLE);
    pr_info("%s: ret %d\n", __func__, ret);
    do_exit(0);

    return ret;
}
```